# Android notification, how to call custom function after click on button?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a simple notification with three buttons. How can i call custom function after button click. I red, that here should be used pending intent, but i did not find any useful example.

**Here is my code:**

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
// I WOULD LIKE TO CALL THIS INTENT OR CUSTOM FUNCTION 
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "123456789"));

        // build notification
        // the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                .setContentText("Subject")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", phoneCallIntent) //CUSTOM INTENT OR FUNCTION CALLING
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent)
                .build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

How can i do it please?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `PendingIntent`. Here's how to create one from an `Intent`:

```
PendingIntent pendingPhoneCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE, phoneCallIntent, 0);
```

Then use `pendingPhoneCallIntent` instead of `phoneCallIntent` in `addAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [Notification.Builder setContentIntent(PendingIntent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

> public Notification.Builder setContentIntent (PendingIntent intent) Supply a PendingIntent to be sent when the notification is clicked.

so before building the `Notification` you need to make a `PendingIntent` like this

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode,phoneCallIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//requestCode is Private request code for the sender like 0,1,2 etc
```

and then

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
```

Now by doing this when you click on the notification the the `pIntent` `PendingIntent` will be sent so that `phoneCallIntent` `Intent` will performed.